# Pointer address weirdness in upper 4 bytes of a C program

Tags: c, x86-64

In a part of a program I have printed out the same pointer in two different ways.

```
vpx_codec_iface_t *ptr = vpx_codec_vp9_cx();
printf("ptr1 %p\n", ptr);
printf("ptr2 %p\n", vpx_codec_vp9_cx());
```

This strangely results in the following output.

```
ptr1 FFFFFFFFDAF9CED0
ptr2 00000000DAF9CED0
```

Playing around with the program, I can "fix" the error by adding some code, or adding some newlines.

```
int x = 0;
vpx_codec_iface_t *ptr = vpx_codec_vp9_cx();
printf("ptr1 %p\n", ptr);
printf("ptr2 %p\n", vpx_codec_vp9_cx());
printf("x=%d\n", x);
```

This results in the following output.

```
ptr1 0000000066A7CED0
ptr2 0000000066A7CED0
x=0
```

What could be causing this behavior? I'm using the Visual Studio 2019 compiler on Windows 10, compiling for x64. The function call `vpx_codec_vp9_cx()` is implemented in `vpxmd.lib` which comes from the `libvpx` project.

Edit: I'm still going through your answers and comments, but I have created a minimal example below. Unfortunately it involves building the whole of the vpx library so it would take me some time to simplify that part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vpx/vpx_encoder.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("This is main\n");
  vpx_codec_iface_t *ptr = vpx_codec_vp9_cx();
  int x = 0;
  printf("ptr1 %p\n", ptr);
  printf("ptr2 %p\n", vpx_codec_vp9_cx());
  printf("x=%d\n", x);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: That's a textbook sign extension problem, but since [`vpx_codec_vp9_cx()` returns a `vpx_codec_iface_t*`](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/master/vpx/vp8cx.h#L45), that doesn't make any sense here. The fact that the problem goes away in your second case suggests UB in your program, but there's none in the code shown. You'll have to try to come up with a [mcve], sorry.

Comment: Okay so it's somewhere else in the program that's causing the issue. I'll shrink it down to a minimal reproducible example - thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see yes

Comment: Technically, you produce undefined behavior by passing a `vpx_codec_iface_t *` as the argument corresponding to a `%p` directive.  It ought first to be converted (by cast, for example) to type `void *`.  It's unclear whether that would resolve your problem, though, and even if it did, that does not rule out an issue elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah, didn't realise it had to be `void*` (though in hindsight that makes total sense). It could be just that simple then.

Comment: Yes, @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0, the specs require a `void *` in particular.  This is consistent with the fact that in general, pointers to different types are not required to have the same size or representation, and the fact that no pointer type is subject to the default argument conversions.  But in practice, I doubt this is actually the OP's issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: yup, MSVC compiling for x86-64 rules out that being the problem.  All pointer types are the same size and use the same object-representation as each other and `intptr_t` on that implementation.  Same for any normal C implementation with a flat memory model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have warnings turned on in your compile environment?   This looks very much like you are missing a prototype for vpx_code_vp9_cx().   In the first case, assignment to ptr, the expected type coercion will sign extend the (default) int valued vpx_codex_vp9_cs().  In the second case, printf, it will be left intact.
A simpler example can be had with:
print.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    void *x = myptr();
    printf("x = %p\n", x);
    printf("myptr() = %p\n", myptr());
    return 0;
}
```

myptr.c:

```
int myptr(void) {
    return 0xd0000020;
}
```

Notice that print.c has no declaration of myptr().  On my system, an unadorned compile: *cc print.c myptr.c -o p* yields:

```
print.c:6:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'myptr' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        void *x = myptr();
                  ^
print.c:6:8: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
      'void *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        void *x = myptr();
              ^   ~~~~~~~
print.c:8:27: warning: format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type
      'int' [-Wformat]
        printf("myptr() = %p\n", myptr());
                          ~~     ^~~~~~~
                          %d
3 warnings generated.
```

my compiler is obviously long-winded, but the point is that every compiler from the past 30 years should report some sort of diagnostic that you should at *least* understand before ignoring.

Comment: Agree, high probability of it being this. Unfortunately without a MCVE in the question it's all just guesswork :(

Comment: Indeed, the compiler was giving a warning which I was ignoring "warning C6066: non-pointer passed as parameter `_Param_(2)` when pointer is required in call to `printf`" and even showing me the function `vpx_codec_vp9_cx()` was (implicitly?) declared as returning `int`. I wasn't aware of this implicit function declaration "feature"!

Comment: It comes from the days before C required function declarations; the default return value was assumed int.   For decades, on most machines, sizeof(int) == sizeof(char *), so it seldom mattered.